# iOS: Use IB to create custom cell for programmatically created UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios5, xcode4.2

I have a view controller where I programmatically add the UITableView. However, I would like to use IB to create my custom UITableViewCell to be used in my programmatically create UITableView. How would I do this if I don't have a UITableView in the controller in IB since I create it programmatically?

I'm using Xcode 4.2.1 with storyboards.

Comment: [see here for a tutorial](http://iphone.galloway.me.uk/iphone-sdktutorials/custom-uitableviewcell/)

Comment: Here's a better one for XCode 4 http://www.altinkonline.nl/tutorials/xcode/uitableview/uitableviewcell/

Comment: @Javy thanks, is there a way to do that within the storyboard so I don't have to create a .xib?

Comment: I remember something in the WWDC videos about being able to set them up in a table vie directly in iOS 5, but I'm stuck back in 4.3 for compatibility reasons.  Sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just create the UITableView programmatically as usual, and in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method use

```
id cell = [dataTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:itemType];
if(!cell)
{
    NSArray *topLevelObject = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:itemType owner:nil options:nil];
    cell = [topLevelObject objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

where itemType is a String with the name of your xib file.

Comment: What do you mean xib file? Do I need to create a UITableViewController in my storyboard?

Comment: The xib file is the file you get when you create your custom UITableViewCell in the Interface Builder.

Comment: I'm not using xib's. I said above I was using storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can add UITableView as subview and implement tableView's methods and this [tutorial](http://www.nomadplanet.fr/2011/01/custom-uitableviewcells-loaded-from-xib-howto-debug/) 
will help you on how to add custom UITablecell to UITableView.